# html5Gallery with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I want to display a gallery of videos in a modal with angular.js so I used  https://html5box.com/ solution. But I have a problem to use my scope variables into class="html5gallery".

```
<div class="html5gallery" data-skin="horizontal" data-width="700" data-height="500" >
<a href="images/Tulip_large.jpg"><img src="images/Tulip_small.jpg" alt="Tulips"></a>
<a  href="{{testscope}}"><img src="images/Colourful_Tulip_small.jpg" alt="{{testscope}}"></a>
<a href="images/Swan_large.jpg"><img src="images/Swan_small.jpg" alt="Swan on Lake"></a>
<a href="images/Big_Buck_Bunny.mp4"><img src="images/Red_Tulip_small.jpg" alt="Red Tulips"></a>
<a href="images/Sakura_Tree_large.mp4"><img src="images/Sakura_Tree_small.jpg" alt="Sakura Trees"></a>
```

it's seems to me that inside class=""html5gallery" i couldn't use angularjs variables its does not grasp {{variable Scope}} 
PS : html5gallery used to display a gallery of videos 
..
if you know other solutions to create gallery videos as html5 gallery do not hesitate to tell it to me

Answer (score 2):

If this HTML is within a controller (or directive) and you have `testScope` properlly set in your scope, then all you need to change is use `ng-href` and `ng-attr-alt` instead of `href` and `alt` so it can be processed by Angular:

```
<div class="html5gallery" data-skin="horizontal" data-width="700" data-height="500" >
  <a href="images/Tulip_large.jpg"><img src="images/Tulip_small.jpg" alt="Tulips"></a>
  <a ng-href="{{testscope}}"><img src="images/Colourful_Tulip_small.jpg" ng-attr-alt="{{testscope}}"></a>
  <a href="images/Swan_large.jpg"><img src="images/Swan_small.jpg" alt="Swan on Lake"></a>
  <a href="images/Big_Buck_Bunny.mp4"><img src="images/Red_Tulip_small.jpg" alt="Red Tulips"></a>
  <a href="images/Sakura_Tree_large.mp4"><img src="images/Sakura_Tree_small.jpg" alt="Sakura Trees"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you still need to escape the $scope variables in directives like {{testScope}}?

Comment: What do you mean by "escape the $scope variables"?

Comment: I mean normally in a directive you could just do something like --> ng-model="someScopeVariable" instead of ng-model="{{someScopeVariable}}, but when you use normal html attributes you would need to escape these variables so angular can process them --> value="{{someScopeVariable}}"

Comment: There are three way of binding variables in angular. The two-way binding such as `ng-model` or the one-way such as `ng-click` take an expression (with no "escaping"). However the third binding is an interpolation used by `ng-href`, `ng-bind` or `ng-src` for instance and requires brackets `{{}}`. You should open a new question if you want to learn more about this.

Comment: thanks @floribon i have tried your proposition but it's seems  they don't understand angularjs inside class="html5gallery" and  when i tried to look into html5gallery class it's an independent page !
you can take a look here: http://outshinesolutions.com/js/html5gallery/html5gallery.js

Comment: @mono: your question was rather brief, and in my experience short questions that don't feature much detail end up in a lot of discussion around answers. Would it perhaps help to add some detail to your question?